# Append "view-source:" to button click url output

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to get the rendered html of a webpage. The **ctrl+u** equivalent (in firefox or chrome).
Currently I must `.click()` load the page, get the url **and then load it again** adding `view-source:` to the url

```
search = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="edit-keys"]')
button = browser.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id="edit-submit"]')
browser.execute_script("arguments[0].value = 'bla';", search[0])
browser.execute_script('arguments[0].target="_blank";', button[0].find_element_by_xpath('./ancestor::form'))
browser.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', button[0])
url = browser.current_url
browser.get("view-source:" + url)
```

Is it possible to do this without loading the url twice?

`browser.execute_script('return document.documentElement.outerHTML')` does not offer the `view-source:` equivalent

`driver.page_source` also does not match `view-source:`

maybe there is a way to add `view-source:` to `browser.execute_script('arguments[0].click();', button[0])`?

Comment: Can you share HTML of form and how desired URL looks like? You can simplify domain name

Comment: @Mike Scotty `driver.page_source` does not solve the issue either (regarding your mentioning possible duplication)

Comment: @Andersson: the desired output would be `view-source:http://www.example.com`. All url I've tested don't look like the `view-source:` …. (methods like `driver.page_source` or `return document.documentElement.outerHTML`) …. Using a button click is forcing me to load all/any url twice to receive the `view-source:http://www.example.com` and then call `browser.find_element_by_css_selector('body').text` for that url to get `view-source` into a variable

Comment: I've retracted the close vote. It might be worth mentioning in your question that you've already tried ``driver.page_source``.

Comment: thank you. is done!

Answer (score 0):

to get the rendered HTML with dynamic JS loaded elements and all you will need to get it with JS with a simple one-liner:

```
rendered_source = driver.execute_script('return document.documentElement.outerHTML;')
```

Comment: try it on this page …. It is not close to matching the `View Page Source` … compare the two results on `https://www.diffchecker.com/diff`

Comment: it's definitely different, the view-source "hack" is formatted and prettified, parsed by the browser, the other is the raw HTML as received from the server plus any dynamic mods made by JS, this is the HTML the JS engine is working with

Comment: The reason I ask is, extensions like ublock or adblock … block properly on `View Page Source` …. but they don't on `return document.documentElement.outerHTML;` … this is how I discovered it is **not only formatting that is incorrect** … but dynamic content too